# ReactJS setState for infinitely nested object

Tags: reactjs

I am having a hard time with using setState in reactJS when it comes to deep nestings while not directly mutating the state.

Right now I have a categories array, each category can contain other categories, and so on ... here is an example:

[image]

There are only 3 levels here but there can really be infinite levels.

Now what I need to do is to drag a category of a level to any other level, for example I can drag the whole **Clothes** category section to under the phone category section.

[image]

I have achieved this using native drag and drop functions and its pretty intuitive. Now the hard part is actually how to do setState. The function I am calling when drag ends looks like this

```
  handleDragEnd(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    let dragCategory = this.state.dragCategory; // category I am dragging
    let dragOverCategory = this.state.dragOverCategory; // category I am dragging into/over

    dragOverCategory.categories.push(dragCategory); // put drag category into dragging into category

    // set from the top level categories
    this.setState({ categories: ??? });
  }
```

I have a dragCategory and a dragOverCategory which should be enough information to know how to push the first into the latter. But it's setState here that's troubling me here as I can only setState from top level (categories). In angularJS we don't even need the setState part and this would work. I know reactJS gives you more freedom of when to setState and trigger render but this is also giving me countless hours of headache for a pretty simple action. Please somebody help me =(

Comment: Isn't setState({ categories: dragOverCategory }) is fine?

Comment: @YatinGaikwad no because categories here is always level 1, while dragOverCategory can be level 1, 2, 3, etc .. you can only setState from the top level, which means if I change categories[0].categories[1].categories[2] ... I don't know how to set it back

Comment: @YatinGaikwad for example here: categories at level 1 is "Clothes" and "Electronics", but dragOverCategory here is category that belongs to level 2 which is "Phones"